# Update a postgis table with the resuly of SQL Executor

Tags: postgis, fme-form

I have built a workflow in FME2015 in which I use SQLExecutor to run a query. I want to use the result of the query to UPDATE a column of table in my database.
I am having difficulties in passing the results into the table using a postgis writer with a writer mode in UPDATE.
I attach a screenshot of my workflow:

[image]

The column I want to update is called: nettype. And I need to update it based on the key: fr_gid. If I understand correctly I need to use the fme_where attribute but I am not sure in what way.

Comment: does the databaseUpdater works for u ?

Comment: I think the databaseUpdater can do what I want but in the end I used the SQLExecutor with the appropriate UPDATE query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use tranformer [databaseUpdater](http://docs.safe.com/fme/2016.0/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Desktop_Help.htm#../Subsystems/FME_Transformers/Content/Transformers/databaseupdater.htm) 
Update fields in a database table based on the condition specified.